# c# for loops - adding and subtracting totals

Tags: c#

I am creating a pizza menu for a college project and I have a drinks section. I have a numericupdown for the user to select the amount of the certain drink they would like. I have been able to create a for loop for adding onto the total when the value of the numericupdown is increased but I am struggling to find out a way to subtract £0.90 from the total value when the value of the numericupdown is decreased.

**Code for the cola numericupdown**

```
private void numCola_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
  {
   Total = Total + Cola;
   lblTotal.Text = Total.ToString("C");
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Now I have found out I need to create a new event which is updating totals, I have added this method to my cheese pizza and extra cheese. However when I have selected both of these (Total = £4.00) and then I have 1 cola, the first cola only charges £0.40 instead of £0.90.

```
        private void UpdateTotal()
        {
            Total = Convert.ToDouble(radCheeseTrad.Checked) * CheeseTraditional;
            Total += Convert.ToDouble(chkCheeseExtraCheese.Checked) * ExtraCheese;
            Total += Convert.ToDouble(numCola.Value) * Cola;
            lblTotal.Text = $"{Total:C}";
        }

        private void numCola_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateTotal();
        }

        private void radCheeseTrad_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            lstOrder.Items.Add("Cheese and Tomato Traditional");
            UpdateTotal();
        }

        private void chkCheeseExtraCheese_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            lstOrder.Items.Add("Extra Cheese");
            UpdateTotal();
            chkCheeseExtraCheese.Checked = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to make this work. I had to create a new event which was updating totals.

```
        private void UpdateTotal()
        {
            Total = Convert.ToDouble(numCola.Value) * Cola;
            lblTotal.Text = $"{Total:C}";
        }

        private void numCola_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateTotal();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your loop performs multiplication through repeated addition. It is better to do it though actual multiplication. You also set the label in a loop; although it works, only the last assignment has any effect, because the UI does not get to display transient values assigned to the label's text while your loop is still in control.

In order to do that, you need to keep a collection of items being purchased, along with the count for each item. Then the total is computed as a sum of products of per-unit prices times the number of items being purchased:

```
// This is pseudo-code; you will need to substitute your actual
// collections when you make them.
private void num_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    decimal total = 0;
    foreach (var product in products) {
        // Get numeric up-down for product
        var numUpDown = ...
        total += Convert.ToInt32(numUpDown.Value) * product.Price;
    }
    lblTotal.Text = total.ToString("C");
}
```

Note that this approach lets you use the same event handler for all products.

Comment: Thank you @dasblinkenlight - I am still trying to work this out but hopefully I will sort it soon. I am still quite new to C# and this is new for me.